# Problems with Eclipse file explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, file, libraries, explorer

I have problems with eclipse file explorer, when i add a library, this library is an android application, when i try to add it, can not select any files, have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: first add project in java build path http://www.rndblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/JavaBuildPathProjects.png

Comment: The "add" button is disabled